# Correct Use of CUDA shared memory for 2D Non-contiguous data access

Tags: cuda

I have a basic question related to Two-dimensional thread access.
I want to copy the non-contiguous data into contiguous buffer and the use of cuda memcopy can be illustrated as:

```
void pack_cuda(float *dstbuf, IOV *srciov, int num_iov)
{
  int i;
  float *ptr;
  ptr = buf;
  for (i = 0; i < num_iov; i++) {
    cudaMemcpy(ptr, srciov[i].bufaddr, srciov[i].len, cudaMemcpyDefault);
  ptr = (char *)ptr + srciov[i].len;
  }
}
```

*srciov stores the start memory address and length of each non-contiguous data in an array of structure.

*dstbuf will store the packed contiguous data after the completion of the function.

Now, I want to implement it using CUDA kernels.

```
__global__ void pack_cuda(float *dstbuf, IOV *srciov, int num_iov)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int k;
  extern __shared__ size_t tmpdbuflen[16*3]; //suppose num_iov is 16

  if ( j == 0 ){
    if ( i < 16 ){
     tmpdbuflen[i] = (srciov[i].len);   //store length to calculate presum
     tmpdbuflen[i+16] = tmpdbuflen[i];  //store length
     tmpdbuflen[i+32] = ((srciov+i)->bufaddr) - (srciov->bufaddr); //store addr difference
    }
    __syncthreads();


    for ( k = 0; k < i; k++)
      tmpdbuflen[i] += srciov[k].len;
  }

  __syncthreads();

  if ( i < 16 && j < srciov[i].len ){  //wondering whether this is correct use
    dst[tmpdbuflen[i] + j] = *(src + tmpdbuflen[i+32] + j);
  }

  __syncthreads();
}
```

Kernel invocation part:

```
dim3 dimblock(16, 16);  //the length of each non-contiguous data is less than 16 
dim3 dimgrid(1,1);
const unsigned int shm_size = sizeof(size_t) * 16 * 3;
pack_cuda<<<dimgrid, dimblock, shm_size, 0>>>(dstbuf, srciov, num_iov);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

However, it seems that I cannot pack all needed datas into dst buffer. 
Sometimes only j = 0 and 1 (with corresponding various i) get packed.
I think the major problem is the usage of shared memory. I only use column 0 threads (threadIdx.y == 0) to copy information onto the shared memory. Then all threads (no restriction on threadIdx.y) will access and read information in shared memory.
How to modify the code enable such design?

I'd appreciate it if anyone can figure out my problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints on your code:

```
__global__ void pack_cuda(float *dstbuf, IOV *srciov, int num_iov)
{
  int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int k;
  extern __shared__ size_t tmpdbuflen[16*3]; //suppose num_iov is 16
```

This Block here will only be executed by one thread, due to the guard `j==0` which only allows thread `bid*bdim+tid = 0*0+0`, ergo thread 0 in block 0, which is undesirable for you. I would guess you want put `j < 16` there

```
  if ( j == 0 ){
    if ( i < 16 ){
     tmpdbuflen[i] = (srciov[i].len);   //store length to calculate presum
     tmpdbuflen[i+16] = tmpdbuflen[i];  //store length
     tmpdbuflen[i+32] = ((srciov+i)->bufaddr) - (srciov->bufaddr); //store addr difference
    }
    __syncthreads();


    for ( k = 0; k < i; k++)
      tmpdbuflen[i] += srciov[k].len;
  }
```

.